# Apple Catalina Error in PLIST, plutil -lint says its OKAY

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, launchd, plist

plutil -lint /Library/LaunchDaemons/net.varela.wesley.borg.plist
/Library/LaunchDaemons/net.varela.wesley.borg.plist: **OK**

sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/net.varela.wesley.borg.plist
/Library/LaunchDaemons/net.varela.wesley.borg.plist: **Invalid or missing service identifier**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
      <key>Borg</key>
        <string>net.wesley.borg</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/Users/wesley/BorgData/borgBackup.sh</string>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
          <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>12</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
          </dict>
      </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: First key should be `Label` not `Borg` and its value in should match the plist name (minus the `.plist`).  Is it supposed to be `net.varela.wesley.borg` or  `net.wesley.borg`?

Comment: @lx07 thanks for the quick reply, I just took out my last name for privacy, must have missed a spot. 
I see, the Label is the Key and the value is the string. 
and yes, its net.varela.wesley.borg for the name and net.varela.wesley.borg.plist
they do match
I fixed that, but still no joy.